# ASP.MVC handle errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET Web Forms,i would accomplish that easily:

```
[...]
try
{
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("abc");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

Now the question is:How can i do the same in ASP.NET MVC?
Ive been looking for it and all i found is [HandleError] attribute.I dont want to redirect user to a "Error.aspx" View if an exception occurs.I want to show error messages in the same page like in Web Forms.

Any Ideias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("abc");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   ViewData["Error"] = ex.Message;
}
return View();
```

In your view or master page, check to see if ViewData["Error"] is set.  If so, display your error div.

```
<% if (ViewData["Error"] != null)
{
    <div class="error"><%=html.encode(ViewData["Error"]) %></div>
}
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try 
{ 
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("abc"); 
} 
catch(Exception ex) 
{ 
   ModelState.AddModelError("date", ex)
}
```

then in the view

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
```

Comment: I use ModelState with reglar (not strongly typed) views all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own attribute which implements [IExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iexceptionfilter.onexception.aspx). You could also return the same View, and set a value in the ViewData, but an attribute would give you a more standard way to handle it.